# CoordinatorLayout/AppBarLayout ExpandableListView being rendered off screen

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

Yet more problem in using CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout.

I'm trying to achieve the basic functionality of having the Toolbar scroll off screen when scrolling down and coming back on screen when scrolling up.

However, my current set up is showing a problem: Not only is the Toolbar not scrolling off, the ListView seems to be rendering off screen at the bottom. It's almost as if it's been offset by the AppBarLayout height.

Here is a gif describing the issue, note that the final item is cut off also the ScrollBar is off screen:

[image]

My layout is pretty standard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:background="@color/background">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:dividerHeight="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer at let me know if it worked

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CoordinatorLayout only works with RecyclerView or NestedScrollView.Try Wrapping your ExapandableListView inside NestedScrollView or use the below code to make NestedScrollingEnable for ExpandableListView.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     expandablelistView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}else {
     CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mSwipeLayout.getLayoutParams();
     params.bottomMargin = heightOfAppBarCompat;
     mSwipeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

**Edit** You can make scrolling work as expected pre-21 with the else statement.

Comment: Yup, setting nested scrolling enabled on the ExpandableListView fixes it. I've added in a hack to your answer for pre v21 devices, hope you don't mind.

Comment: how about SwipeRefreshLayout?

Comment: You can now use `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled((View view, boolean enabled)` for compatibilty purposes. Didn't check if it really works on older API.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it as a comment, but in terms of readability I will drop this info as an answer. If it won't work, let me know and I will delete it...
I guess you should tell your Toolbar how to interact. In my app the toolbar looks like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

please note the "app:layout_collapseMode"

Answer (score 0):

```
private int mPreviousVisibleItem;


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        expListView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    } else {
        expListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (firstVisibleItem > mPreviousVisibleItem) {
                    appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true);
                } else if (firstVisibleItem < mPreviousVisibleItem) {
                    appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true);
                }
                mPreviousVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
            }
        });
    }
```