# ExpandableListView in Coordinatorlayout

Tags: java, android, layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to implement `ExpandableListView` in `Coordinatorlayout`.
I am able to fill data and show, but ExpandableList is not getting expanded when I keep 
`android:layout_height="wrap_content/match_parent/fill_parent"` but when I do `android:layout_height="500dp"`, it gets expanded.

My child view has height of 100dp so, for 5 items in the list, 500dp works fine.

Below is the part of code.
layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com..example.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">


            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#cccccc"/>

                <ExpandableListView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/lvExp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="500dp"
                    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewInterface{

    private Intent myIntent;
    private RequestQueue queue;
    AdapterView listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<ITEM>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // get the listview

            expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
            expListView.setFocusable(false);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                expListView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
            }

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });


            prepdata();

            // Listview Group click listener
            expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded"+(height+6)*10,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void prepdata(){

        //Start Data Prep
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<ITEM>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Choose your options1");
        listDataHeader.add("Choose your options2");


        // Adding child data
        List<ITEM> options = new ArrayList<ITEM>();

        ITEM item1 = new ITEM("Burger King1", "Rs 491", "YesOff","Haveit1");
        ITEM item2 = new ITEM("Burger King2", "Rs 492", "YesOff","Haveit2");
        ITEM item3 = new ITEM("Burger King3", "Rs 493", "YesOff","Haveit3");
        ITEM item4 = new ITEM("Burger King4", "Rs 494", "YesOff","Haveit4");
        ITEM item5 = new ITEM("Burger King5", "Rs 495", "YesOff","Haveit5");

        options.add(item1);
        options.add(item2);
        options.add(item3);
        options.add(item4);
        options.add(item5);
        // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), options);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), options);
        //End Data Prep

        listAdapter = new AdapterView(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello ! Did you look at this post ? [ExpandableListView in CoordinatorLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867779/coordinatorlayout-appbarlayout-expandablelistview-being-rendered-off-screen?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, I did but it didn't help.

Comment: Improve formatting

Answer (score 0):

`ExpandableListView` are weird with `CoordinatorLayout`. Moreover, you don't find many docs about their `ScrollBehaviour` when you wrap them into a `CoordinatorLayout`.

I had the same issue, but I solved it by placing my ExpandableListView into a `SwipeRefreshLayout`, telling both of them how they should behave.
Here is my working layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_expandable_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/expandable_list"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Note that using a `SwipeRefreshLayout` will allow the action of scrolling to the top to *"visualy make the action of refreshing data"*.

To disable this, in your onCreate() method, inflate your xml and write this :

```
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefresh);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false); // disables swipe bottom scroll AND refresh dialog
```

**PS :** I don't know if you're going to face the same issue I then got, which was my `AppBar` wrapping a part of my last List group. I had to add this block to fix the issue (everything is in the comments) :

```
// Enables scroll under appbar, AND makes parent view consider the height of the AppBar to add
        // to the bottom of the page so the ExpandableScrollView last group isn't wrapped.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { // >= API 21 version
            listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        }else { // < API 21 version
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mSwipeLayout.getLayoutParams();
            AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_expandable_list_view);

            TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
            getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true);
            int heightOfAppBarCompat = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(tv.resourceId); //gets the height of the AppBar
            params.bottomMargin = heightOfAppBarCompat;
            mSwipeLayout.setLayoutParams(params); //sets the AppBar height as layout_marginBottom of the ExpandableListView
        }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I did Something like This.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">


                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/budget_app_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/eight_dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/eight_dp"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/sixteen_dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/budget"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/twenty_four_sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/total_amount_budget_activity"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="end|right"
                        android:text="$ 5000"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/twenty_four_sp" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/category_count_TV_budget_activity"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/eight_dp"
                    android:text="2 items in 3 Categories"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp" />


                <include layout="@layout/add_categegories_layout" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <com.tacktile.contassist.helper.classes.NonScrollExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expand_list_budget_activity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"
         />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Custom ExpandableListView **NonExpandableListView** for CordinateLayout.
src: [Android - NestedScrollView which contains ExpandableListView doesn't scroll when expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37605545/3863332)
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605908/3863332

```
public class NonScrollExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {

    public NonScrollExpandableListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonScrollExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NonScrollExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```